# Tikz package "animations" - Print final version

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, printing

I am using Beamer and the Tickz package to put two boxes around some images. 
When compiling beamer places 3 slides as it should (one without boxes, one with first box and one with two boxes).
But for printing, I would like to have the final slide with the boxes. 
Below the code I am using.

```
\begin{frame}{Unrelated optimal rule of thumb} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.7\textheight]{SomeImage.png}};
            \draw<2->[red,ultra thick,rounded corners]  (1.85,4.25) rectangle (2.6,4.70);
            \draw<3->[red,ultra thick,rounded corners]  (2.4,2.8) rectangle (4.2,0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `handout` as an option for the `beamer` document class.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```